# How can I change chrome://flags using chrome API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just started using the Chrome Extensions API and there is this one settings page with experimental features and I need to change some of them. How can I change these settings with the API?

chrome://flags <= Experimental Features

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: @DanielHerr Realy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental) about *chrome.experimental.*API*.

It includes here the steps on how to use this API.

To enable this API in your browser, you can do this in either of the two ways:

- Go to `chrome://flags`, find "Experimental Extension APIs", click its "Enable" link, and restart Chrome. From now on, unless you return to that page and disable experimental APIs, you'll be able to run extensions and apps that use experimental APIs.
- Specify the `--enable-experimental-extension-apis` flag each time you launch the browser. On Windows, you can do this by modifying the properties of the shortcut that you use to launch Google Chrome. For example: **`path_to_chrome.exe --enable-experimental-extension-apis`**

> Caution: Don't depend on these experimental APIs. They might
>   disappear, and they will change. Also, the Chrome Web Store doesn't
>   allow you to upload items that use experimental APIs.